# pyqgis: AttributeError: 'QgsRasterLayer' object has no attribute 'drawingStyle'

Tags: pyqgis

I am following http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html. In python console after a raster layer is loaded to a variable "rlayer"

```
>>>rlayer
  <qgis.core.QgsRasterLayer object at 0x113faadf8>

>>>rlayer.drawingStyle()
  Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
         AttributeError: 'QgsRasterLayer' object has no attribute 'drawingStyle'

>>>rlayer.setDrawingStyle(QgsRasterLayer.SingleBandPseudoColor)
  Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
         AttributeError: type object 'QgsRasterLayer' has no attribute 'SingleBandPseudoColor'


>>>rlayer.setColorShadingAlgorithm(QgsRasterLayer.PseudoColorShader)
   Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
         AttributeError: 'QgsRasterLayer' object has no attribute 'setColorShadingAlgorithm'
```

what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I used an alternative method which might help you.

In stead of changing properties of your raster layer, you can assign a prepared style to a layer:

```
rlayer.loadNamedStyle("c:/some/folder/tree/style01.qml")
# and look at canvas if it did what you want
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the method is outdated since qgis 2.10 (or so).
According to the QGIS API you directly have to use the `.setRenderer()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the drawing style works with :

```
rlayer.setDrawingStyle("SingleBandPseudoColor")
```

But i'm still struggling with the other errors ...